# Is there a way to programatically trigger google voice to text functionality available via android keyboard?

Tags: android, react-native, speech-to-text, google-voice

I'm working on a React Native app and want to programmatically trigger google speech to text on click of a button. Is there a way to do it? I need a solution for both Android and ioS.

Note: Tried https://github.com/react-native-community/voice, but it doesn't work.

[image: Voice to text functionality]

Comment: Interested in this too, for both Android and iOS. But I'm afraid it can't be achieved.

Comment: @honey thakuria, were you able to achieve this ? I'm also facing similar problem.